# Lightbox2 images fail to load

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I use lightbox2 for my gallery and it works fine, except the next, prev, close and loading buttons aren't loaded. They are located in "public/images". I use ExpressJS. The error thrown is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and "Cannot GET /images/loading.gif/".

Tried placing a directory called "images" containing the afformentioned files in different places and it didn't work. Also, when I click the error, the Network tab in chrome dev-tools identifies its type as "text/html", and I suspect that here might lay the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra `/` in your path, e.g., you have `/images/loading.gif/`, but it should be `/images/loading.gif`

Comment: Wasn't that. I placed those files inside another folder in my "images" folder and of course changed the path accordingly. That worked for me. And also, for some peculiar reason, I had to change the filenames of lightbox css and js-plus-jquery because chrome had difficulties uploding them. I guess it got something to do with bootstrap or node express, not sure. Anyway it works fine now.